# How to use Unix epoch time values with Postgres tsrange and tstzrange types?

Tags: postgresql

**Is it possible to insert Unix epoch time values into a field of type tstzrange/tsrange without converting to some other time string format first?**

Using Postgres 9.3, an invalid input syntax error is produced when tstzrange/tsrange are supplied with to_timestamp() values:

```
=> select '["to_timestamp(1267253400.069539)",]'::tstzrange;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "to_timestamp(1267253400.069539)"
LINE 1: select '["to_timestamp(1267253400.069539)",]'::tstzrange;
```

which is a bit confusing given that to_timestamp() returns a value with type timestamp with time zone.

It is not as simple as functions not being allowed for fields of these types because the now() function works fine:

```
=> select '["now()",]'::tstzrange;
               tstzrange
---------------------------------------
["06-OCT-14 15:11:05.488949 -07:00",)
(1 row)
```

The solution I'm using now is to convert the epoch times to formatted strings (e.g. '2010-02-27T06:50:00.069539-00'), which work fine with tstzrange/tsrange.  I presume this is not as efficient as supplying epoch times directly and would appreciate knowing if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `=> select '["to_timestamp(1267253400.069539)",]'::tstzrange;`

That's not supplying a `tstzrange` with `to_timestamp` output.

It's trying to use the text string `"to_timestamp(1267253400.069539)"` as the literal value of the first half of a timestamp range.

You'll want to use the convenient function form constructor:

```
select tstzrange( to_timestamp(1267253400.069539),null );
```

... as that way any contained expressions get evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, the constructors are exactly what I need.  I'm still a bit confused as why the example with now() works, it is clearly evaluating that expression.

Comment: @terse `now()` is a very weird special case. I really want to remove all references to that from the examples in the documentation, relegating it to the appendix that's all that such a messy historical hack warrants. Essentially PostgreSQL treats the string literal `now()` as a special case timestamp representation when parsing, implicitly converting it to the current timestamp. That's why it's valid to cast `now()` to a timestamp. These days you should just use the `current_timestamp` pseudo-function instead.